# SVN setup with visual studio code IDE(v 1.12.1.) (for Nativescript-Cli projects)

Tags: svn, visual-studio-code, angular2-nativescript

I am using Nativescript-cli extension in visual studio code IDE to develop hybrid application. Here i need to synchronize/commit code base periodically in to SVN url(like https:///svn/HotelAppMobile/) like SVN repositories in eclipse.

My development environment - 
1.visual studio code IDE - version 1.12.1.
2.Current Framework - Nativescript-Cli(Nativescript with angular)

I have tried with extension [tortoise-svn-for-vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cdsama.tortoise-svn-for-vscode) in visual studio code. but i did't get any proper documentations on how to use this extension.

please suggest any other extension or idea to accomplish my need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same problem.

You have to install TortoiseSVN https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html (not just the extension) locally and set up a local SVN sync directory and sync it, before you can open it in vscode and use the extension to commit changes from within vscode via right click the file -> "SVN...".